Not able to run selenium jar file using testng.xml from command line
I am trying to run a Selenium Java Test (jar file) build on Gradle using TestNG.xml from the command line.
Note: I am able to successfully run the test case from IntelliJ.
But when I package the project in a .jar file and try to run it from the CLI (Windows 11 powershell), its throwing an error.
On running the Below code
java -cp untitled-0.1-all.jar org.testng.TestNG Testng.xml

Getting this error:

[main] ERROR org.testng.TestNG - Cannot find class in classpath:
com.xyz.Test1

Project Structure and Code is on Github.

Test1 Class Code:
Its a simple test class opens up chrome browser using selenium and verifies title of the page.
package com.xyz;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.time.Duration;

public class Test1 {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Starting the test");

        //Opening the Chrome brower
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        //Opening google page and verifying the title
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
        String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
        Assert.assertEquals(actualTitle, "Google");

        //Close the chrome browser
        driver.quit();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>> Ending the test");
    }
}

Testng.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.xyz.Test1" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>

build.gradle
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
}

group = 'xyz'
version = '0.1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

shadowJar {
    // Include test resources
    from 'src/test/resources'

    // Include test code
    from 'src/test/java'
}

dependencies {
    //Add impementation & testImplementation as was not sure if this was the source of problem.
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.26.0'
    implementation 'org.testng:testng:7.10.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.9'
    implementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.8.0'

    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:7.10.2'
    testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.26.0'
    testImplementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.8.0'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.xyz.Test1'
    }
}

test {
    useTestNG()
}

From the powershell (Windows 11) ran the following commands:
> gradle clean
> gradle shadowJar


Then ran the below command
> java -cp .\build\libs\untitled-0.1-all.jar org.testng.TestNG .\src\test\resources\Testng.xml

Getting this error
[main] ERROR org.testng.TestNG -
Cannot find class in classpath: com.xyz.Test1

I have further checked the .Jar file and it contained the com.xyz.Test1 Class (screenshot below for reference)


Test1 is in test folder, so compiled Test1.class wont be in the all.jar, can you try to put that to src/main/java and Testing.xml to src/main/resource and retry ?

@ozkanpakdil :  In the shawdowJar (in build.gradle) I have mentioned the src/test/java to be added to in the jar. If you look at the last screenshot (in question) the packaged jar contains the Test1.java file.

Test1.java is not Test1.class, it should be compiled(meaning Test1.class) and put into jar, java text file itself in jar does not mean much for jre. JRE expects compiled class AFAIK

I did as you suggested now I can Test1.class, but still getting the same error.

any chance can you share a small reproducer in gitlab or github ?

Hi @ozkanpakdil here is the github link. https://github.com/alok-singh380/Temp_StackOverflow

According to 3.4. Running TestNG, the syntax for running from CLI is:
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]

So the command to execute should look about like this:
gradle build && java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

This assumes testng.xml not to be put into the resources directory.
During test-development, switches -log or -verbose may be useful.

Also see Testing in Java & JVM projects... if this still results in Cannot find class in classpath, you may have to configure the class-path for source-set test, which is usually not required, when using the default src/test directory.
